# IDA Pro: JDWP error: ABSENT_INFORMATION - Desired information is not available

Tags: ida, debugging, android

I am trying to debug a dex file from an APK file in IDA Pro. I set some breakpoints when launching the activity. When I start the process, the application waits for the debugger. After some time, IDA Pro shows this JDWP error: ABSENT_INFORMATION and breakpoint can not set. The application runs normally.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try debugging on a device that has a less recent API level (try 27 or lower). I remember a similar issue that I resolved by running a not-too-recent Android version via the emulator bundled with Android Studio.